# Edit Cell Text in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, text

In my app I have a set number of cells in a UITableView, 10, no more, no less, and the user can't change that.

However what I would like to have is so that if the user was to naturally in an iOS fashion, swipe a cell, or press an edit button, the cell text becomes editable with a simple tap on the cell bringing up a keyboard.

I was just wondering if there is a fairly simple method to do this, or take quite of custom building? What are you thoughts on how this could go together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you just add a UITextField into the table cell's contentView I believe.